# php scripts to generate 1000 contact lists

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, database, random

This code is supposed to generate 1000 contacts randomly from the inserted value, but it does not work.. can someone please look over it and help me to find the problems. Thank you.....
here is the URL http://web-students.armstrong.edu/~jl4303/contactForm.html you can click the link, view generator. it just doesnt work....

```
   <?php 
 //Mysql informatino login information
    $host="localhost"; 
   $username="xxxx"; 
   $password="xxxx"; 
   $db_name="xxxx"; 
  //Mysql connection
   mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
   mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
  //generate array
  $totalContacts=1000;

   $fName =
   array('Michelle','Jing','Mike','Ricky','David','Matt',
  'Melony','Alex','Andrew','Sally','Sue');
   $lName =array('Smith','Lee','Dobson','Johnson','Zammit','Brown','Jones',
  'Miller','Garcia','Wilson','Martinez');
   $Streets=array('Central Ave','Broadway','1st St','2nd St','3rd St','Washington St',
  'Jefferson Ave','Woodcreek Blvd');
   $stateList = array(
  'AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','DC','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA','KS','KY',
  'LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN');
  $domains = array('yahoo.com','mail.com','gmail.com','example.net','host.org');

  for($i=0; $i < totalContacts; $i++){
  $data = array(
 'firstName' => gFirst(), 
 'lastName' => gLast(),
 'address' => gAddress(),
 'state' => gState(),
 'zip' => gZip(),
 'email' =>gEmail (),
 'phone' => gPhone(),
    );
   };
```

**// i am not sure about the insert value here...**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(fName, lName, Address, City, State, Zip, 
Phone,Email)VALUES('$fName', '$lName', '$Address', '$City', '$State', '$Zip', 
'$Phone', '$Email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

function gFirst() {
global $firstNames;
return $firstNames[array_rand($firstNames)];
}
`enter code here`function gLast() {
global $lastNames;
return $lastNames[array_rand($lastNames)];
};

function gStreet() {
global $streets;
$houseNumber = mt_rand(1,3000);
$street = $streets[array_rand($streets)];
return $houseNumber.' '.$street;
};

function gState() {
global $stateList;
return $stateList[array_rand($stateList)];
};

function gZip() {
return str_pad(mt_rand(0,99999),5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
};

function gEmail() {
global $domains;
$randomCharacters = md5(mt_rand());
$firstIndex = mt_rand(3,7); // length
$user = substr($randomCharacters,0,$firstIndex);
$domain = $domains[array_rand($domains)];
return $user.'@'.$domain;
};


function gPhone() {
$areacode = mt_rand(100,999);
$first3 = mt_rand(100,999);
$last4 = mt_rand(1000,9999);
return $areacode.'-'.$first3.'-'.$last4;
};

?>
```

This php script will be a file link into my main page, supposely, when I click the link, the database will automatically generate 1000 random contacts based on the values that I have inserted. but it doesnt work for somehow, I think it is the insert part that I did not do it right, but there isnt any error message when debugging, not sure what should I do from here, should I just print out the data? I am new, if the question seems stupid please don't mind me, I am still learning, so can someone please help me with this .... I appreciated very much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: You are storing the random values in an array called data, your insert query needs to be values($data['firstName'], $data['lastName'], etc..) also you need to append to it instead of overwriting $data

Comment: Mauricio, thank you, how do I append to it ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Mauricio, from my understanding, i should do:for($i=0; $i < totalContacts; $i++){
 array_push($fName,$lName,$address,$Street,... $i);
 ); am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is - 1) you are using the same variables for insertion that you are using for storing your data. 2) City is missing in your insert (e.g. no `gCity()` method available). Alternatively, there is a `gStreet()` which is not used anywhere. Please clean up the code a bit first, then try this -

```
for($i=0; $i < totalContacts; $i++){

    $data = array(
   'firstName' => gFirst(), 
   'lastName' => gLast(),
   'address' => gAddress(),
   'state' => gState(),
   'zip' => gZip(),
   'email' =>gEmail (),
   'phone' => gPhone(),
    );

   $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (
          fName, 
          lName, 
          Address, 
          State, 
          Zip, 
          Phone,
          Email)
        VALUES('" . $data['firstName'] . "', '" 
          . $data['lastName'] . "', '" 
          . $data['address'] . "', '" 
          . $data['state'] . "', '" 
          . $data['zip'] . "', '" 
          . $data['email'] . "', '" 
          . $data['phone'] . "', '" 
          . $data['email'] . "')";

     $result=mysql_query($sql);

  };
```

I have put the insert inside the loop here.